# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Double'.'

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I'm currently writing a small app that tracks certain stocks, I have a db with the stock data and want to out put it to a WPF datagrid, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Double'

Forgive my bad coding skills as I haven't done this in a few years, I had a look at the inner exception but it just says null.

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
            {
                StockGrid.ItemsSource = db.LowFloatStocks.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stock.cs

```cs
#region Day 1 Open Variabes

private int stockId;
private string stockTicker;
private double openingPrice;
private double spike;
private double high;
private double low;
private double closingPrice;

private double gainPercent;
private double gapPercent;
private double highPercent;
private double lowPercent;
private double closePercent;

private string greenToRed;
private string redToGreen;
private string closeLessEqualToOpen;
private string closeRed;
private double closeVHigh;
private double closeVOpen;

private string catalyst;
private double stockFloat;
private string dilution;
#endregion


#region Day 2 Open Variables
private double day2Open;
//private decimal day2Spike;
private double day2High;
private double day2Low;
private double day2Close;

private double day2gapPercent;
private double day2highPercent;
private double day2lowPercent;
private double day2ClosePercent;

private string day2GapUp;
private string day2GapDown;
private string day2GreenRed;
private string day2RedGreen;

private string day2CloseLessEqualOpen;
private string day2CloseRed;
private double day2CloseVHigh;
private double day2ClosevOpen;
```

SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LowFloatStocks] (
    [Id]                       INT           NOT NULL,
    [Date]                     DATE          NOT NULL,
    [Ticker]                   NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    [ClosingPrice]             REAL          NOT NULL,
    [OpeningPrice]             REAL          NOT NULL,
    [GainPercent]              AS            (round(([High]-[OpeningPrice])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [GapPercent]               AS            (round(([OpeningPrice]-[ClosingPrice])/[ClosingPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Spike]                    REAL          NOT NULL,
    [1stSpike%]                AS            (round(([Spike]-[OpeningPrice])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [High]                     REAL          NOT NULL,
    [HighPercent]              AS            (round(([High]-[ClosingPrice])/[ClosingPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Low]                      REAL          NOT NULL,
    [LowPercent]               AS            (round(([Low]-[ClosingPrice])/[ClosingPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [1stClose]                 REAL          NOT NULL,
    [ClosePercent]             AS            (round(([1stClose]-[ClosingPrice])/[ClosingPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [greenToRed]               NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [redToGreen]               NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [CloseLessEqualToOpen]     NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [CloseRed]                 NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [ClosevHigh]               AS            (round(([High]-[1stClose])/[1stClose],(4))*(100)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [ClosevOpen]               AS            (round(([OpeningPrice]-[1stClose])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Catalyst]                 NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Float]                    DECIMAL (18)  NOT NULL,
    [Dilution]                 NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2Open]                 REAL          NOT NULL,
    [day2gapPercent]           AS            (round(([Day2Open]-[1stClose])/[1stClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Day2High]                 REAL          NOT NULL,
    [day2HighPercent]          AS            (round(([Day2High]-[1stClose])/[1stClose],(4))*(100)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Day2Low]                  REAL          NOT NULL,
    [Day2LowPercent]           AS            (round(([Day2Low]-[1stClose])/[1stClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Day2Close]                REAL          NOT NULL,
    [Day2ClosePercent]         AS            (round(([Day2Close]-[1stClose])/[1stClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Day2GapUp]                NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2GapDown]              NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2GreenToRed]           NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2RedToGreen]           NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2CloseLessEqualToOpen] NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2CloseRed]             NCHAR (3)     NOT NULL,
    [Day2ClosevHigh]           AS            (round(([Day2Open]-[Day2High])/[Day2Open],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Day2ClosevOpen]           AS            (round(([Day2Open]-[Day2Close])/[Day2Open],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: REAL is not double. REAL is float.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, split your code line: first get your data into a local list, then assign that list to the data grid. Does the error still happen on the db-line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you change all you DBTypes from `REAL` to `FLOAT` or your C# Types from `double` to `float`.

```
DBType REAL is float in C#
DBType FLOAT is double in C#
```

Comment: When I wrote the sql it changed it automatically for some reason

Comment: Ok so I changed the c# types to float and now its saying 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'."

Comment: So... You changed the DB types to float and the C# types to float too? You should not do both.

Comment: Ok DBTypes are REAL and C# types are float?

Comment: Can you show us the Entity and where exactly the exception is thrown. You have also a `DB DECIMAL` that you assign to a double. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) please. Please note that .NET Framework `Single` is the same as C# `float`

Comment: All good, I got it, for some reason when I update the script it changed the floats to Real